# NoReverseMatch at /guardian/guardianhomepage/

Tags: django

**Please feel free too ask more information about this project. What am i doing wrong here .... please help 
I have provided my models, urls, and views picture with error page picture**

**base.html**
[image]
**urls.py**
[image]

**models**

[image]

**hireapp/urls.py**

[image]

**views.py**

[image]

**Error**

[image]

Comment: We need to see your template file. It seems like some thing is wrong with the `guardianprofiles` variable.

Comment: base.html is already given. can you be specific please

Comment: It's not. You showed a screenshot of a part of it. Also, by posting only screenshots it's really difficult to find things in your code.

Comment: The problem isn't with the URL definitions. It's with the data passed to the template. The error seems to be originating from the `GuardianHomepage` view. There's nothing in that view that passes `guardianprofiles` as a context variable (It's only using `tutors`). So my guess is the `guardian_required` decorator is responsible for that? If so, please paste that as well @BlackBoxSql.

Comment: @Zollie I have separated guardian and tutor type of user by flagging them and I wanted that after login the app will automatically recognize the user and will restrict each other to access other urls

Comment: The problem is coming from the wrongly used namespace in your url call in the template. I updated my answer with the more precise description of the problem.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: the mentioned error was not solved but another came up. So I think I need to structure my project properly. my database design also need to be revised I think. and I am running out of time. God help a bad programmer !  Thank you for the concern @Zollie

Comment: There will always be some errors, that’s not a problem, but do not get lost in your own code too much because of the hurry.

Answer (score 0):

I give this again. In your 'nice' images the error message is:

> **Error : NoReverseMatch at /guardian/guardianhomepage/**
>   at line in template:
>
> `{% url 'guardian:guardian_profile_update' guardianprofiles.id %}`

Which means that **Django tries to resolve a url** but it cannot find it. Why?

In the urls.py you normally would use for example:

```
path(‘guardian/guardianprofileupdate/<int:id>/’, guardian.GuardianProfileUpdate.as_view(), name=‘guardian_profile_update’)
```

And it would be resolved. But you however define url patterns with **namespaces** and **instances** of your app. Which **are not reflected** in your template when you try to get a url. The instance namespace of the app is `hireapp`, the namespace of the urlpatterns is `guardian`

Thus if you call a url in your template, you should call that like:

```
{% url 'hireapp:guardian:guardian_profile_update' guardianprofiles.id %}
```

And so on... Otherwise Django is looking for an app named **guardian** which does not exist, thus cannot be resolved.

The named URL **hireapp:guardian:guardian_profile_update** would look for a pattern named `guardian_profile_update` in the namespace `guardian` that is itself defined within the top-level namespace `hireapp`.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned it's difficult to read your code the way it's posted so it would help if you enter it in the text-editor instead of post screenshots. Basically the problem is there is no argument being passed because the view doesn't know which GuardianProfile you are after. You might think it would because user is logged in, so it might automatically understand which GuardianProile is related to which user, but it doesn't work that way because the relationship you have specified is a foreignkey so the user could have multiple profiles. You could consider changing the relationship from user to Guardian/Tutor profiles to a one to one, and then you could access the id with user.guardianprofile.id. (not sure exactly how it works with camelcase) That's the way I would do it as I would think you would only need one Guardian or Tutor profile per user.

Try changing the user field in your GuardianProfile and TutorProfile models:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT,)
```

Make your migrations, migrate, and then try to access the id.